# We are using MSSQL 2016 / SSMS 18.9.2 and trying to script out a system versioned table with 2 hidden columns (is_hidden=1 is the sys.columns table)

Tags: sql-server-2016

When the table was created, we used this for the 2 columns in question:

```
[EffectiveDateUTC] [DATETIME2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL,
[ExpirationDateUTC] [DATETIME2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL,
```

However, when we right click the table in the object explorer and script table as a create, these 2 columns are missing the HIDDEN keyword.  We cannot find any "scripting" option that scripts that.  Does anyone have any ideas what I am missing here to get that to be included in the generated script?

The table scripts fine but it does not script the HIDDEN portion for those 2 columns.  They come back as:

```
[EffectiveDateUTC] [DATETIME2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
[ExpirationDateUTC] [DATETIME2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in SQL Server Management Objects (SMO).  You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/sqlmanagementobjects/issues/65).